# Laravel 5 | How to install and configure "xdebugger" in PHPStrom in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using Laravel 5 in phpStorm and want to start debugging with xdebug.

In My /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini :

```
;xdebug configuration
 zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
 xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
 xdebug.remote_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_port = 9000
 xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
 xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

I get the error:

```
Error running Laravel: Port 9000 is busy
```

Comment: Sorry IDE : phpstrom

Comment: This error seems to come from Laravel and not xdebug or PhpStorm. You need to provide much more info -- e.g. what do you do before you see this error etc.

Comment: I set the Port of "xDebug" server as 8080.

Comment: Also i set 9000, 9001, 10000... But still its loading

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have a good tutorial to install xdebugger on visual studio code.
Please check that.

[Xdebugger Installation on Visual Studio](http://www.rohankumarshrestha.com.np/2018/12/31/installation-php-xdebugger-visual-studio-code-wamp-server-debugging-laravel-project/)